# How to start browser in WebDriver with custom localStorage set

Tags: html, selenium, automation, local-storage, selenium-chromedriver

I want to speed up my Selenium tests and noticed that a lot of time is being spent on login procedure.

Login on web application is implemented via localStorage session token (probably OAuth 2.0). I know how to set it once a browser starts and login page loads:

```
localStorage.setItem(key, value)
```

It works great. But is it possible to make the browser to pick up custom localStorage using Selenium (Java).

Is it profile?

Answer (score 1):

Well this works for me in python

```
driver.excute_script('javascript:localStorage.(funtion of localStorage)')
```

so I suppose well you can set up a validation token like I use for test, and of course I get my `auth_token` from the database first, but it works like this

```
driver.excuteScript('javascript:localStorage.token="your validation token";');
```

should work